# Pagination broke after updateto Wordpress 3.4

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Post Type Pagination Doesn't Work in Wordpress 3.4](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/custom-post-type-pagination-doesnt-work-in-wordpress-3-4)

I updated to wordpress 3.4 and after so my pagination broke showing not found on page/2 etc. I am using custom post types and custom query such as:

```
<?php
  $type = 'products';
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
  $args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,    
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
  );
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query($args);
?>
```

is there any possible fix for that? thank you.

Comment: Try saving your permalinks settings again

Comment: Duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56256/2411

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code?  It's hard to tell without more info, but it looks like you're trying to change the main query but are just running a new one.  If so, you should be using the [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook.  Otherwise your paging links will reflect the main query (which is what you want to modify) instead of the new one that you're showing on the page.