# Custom Post Type Pagination Doesn't Work in Wordpress 3.4

Tags: posts, pagination, customization

I have a problem when using Wordpress 3.4. My "Products" custom post type pagination doesn't work. Here is the code I use

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'products',
'posts_per_page' => PER_PAGE_DEFAULT,
'paged'=>$paged
) );
```

That code works well in previous WP version (Wordpress 3.3.2) but not in current version i.e. 3.4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is this `PER_PAGE_DEFAULT`? Try replacing it with a static value for testing, say 3 and then see if the pagination works.

Comment: It looks like the global problem. Here the some kind of sulution — http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-34-broke-my-paginaton-setup?replies=4#post-2891468 .

Comment: Rutwick Gangurde : PER_PAGE_DEFAULT is a number of posts that equals to 'Blog pages show at most' value in Reading Settings. 

I replaced it with 'posts_per_page' => 3, But it doesn't work also.

Comment: Maxim Orlovsky : Thank you for the link. 

I found the sollution. I replaced class-wp.php file in wp-includes directory with the class-wp.php of 3.3.2 version. The result, pagination works well. In right footer of WP admin still says Version 3.4. It doesn't change the version.

How do you think about this? Is it allowable or not?

Thank you for your responds.

Comment: @KharisBlank this will break as soon as you update to a new version.  Changing core files is a bad idea.  Use the pre_get_posts hook shown in the wordpress.org thread linked above.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. For all: thank your help.

Comment: Maxim Orlovsky: I have fixed the problem by using  suggestion and some code custumizations. 

Evan: Thank you. Now, I do not need to modify WP core.

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_query_var('page')` instead of `get_query_var('paged')`. Related ticket: [#21028](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21028)

Comment: Molnarm: Thank you for you. I added this in functions.php: if ( ! function_exists( 'ucc_add_cpts_to_pre_get_posts' ) ) {
    function ucc_add_cpts_to_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_post_type_archive() && ! is_archive() && ! is_search() && ! is_singular() && ! is_404() ) {
            $my_post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
            if ( empty( $my_post_type ) ) {
                $query->set('post_type', 'products');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ucc_add_cpts_to_pre_get_posts' );

It works without get_query_var